# AOSP Build: How to skip local header from include

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-source

I have made a modification to bluedroid code.

My code  needs to use the *usual* semaphore.h which is located at: `<aosp_root>/prebuilts/ndk/current/platforms/<platform>/<arch>/usr/include/semaphore.h`

Now, in AOSP 6.0+, bluedroid resides in `<aosp_root>/system/bt/`

In there, there is a header at:  `<aosp_root>system/bt/osi/include/semaphore.h`

In usual AOSP build, if I leave a simple `#include <semaphore.h>` in my code, the osi header gets included, which is incompatible. Is there a way to modify the build system so that ndk's header gets used for my code?

I'd happily include from this relative path in my code, but `<arch>` (and probably `<platform>` ) is/are compile time variables, and should not be hardcoded. workarround for this is also welcomed as alternate answer.

[Link to osi's header](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/bt/+/android-6.0.1_r26/osi/include/semaphore.h)
[Link to bluedroid main make file](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/bt/+/android-6.0.1_r26/main/Android.mk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that either I need to give fixed paths to correct header in my code, or -

Since I was modifying bluedroid code anyway, I went ahead and modified bluedroid's semaphore.h too. This line in rouge semaphore.h helps:

`#include_next "semaphore.h"`

gcc extensions FTW. This should continue working till android ndk keeps using gcc..

I know about the general warning that goes with it. Short of writing my own separate semaphore wrapper library based on correct semaphores, this was the only way I could find.

Another alternate I considered was to rename bluedroid's semaphore.h but that will become a maintenance nightmare.